# RabbitMQ consumers die in dockerized environment but not in dev

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

Hope everyone is having a great weekend, I've got the following Subscribe method

```
public void Subscribe(string queueName, Func<string, Task<bool>> onMessageReceived, Action<Exception> onError)
{
    var channel = _connection.CreateModel();
    channel.QueueDeclare(queueName, false, false, false, null);
    var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
    //receive only one message at a time and wait for the method to return before receiving the next message
    channel.BasicQos(0, 1, false);
    consumer.Received += async (model, ea) =>
    {
        var body = ea.Body.ToArray();
        var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" [x] Received {0} , consumer-id {1}", message, ea.ConsumerTag);
            if (!await onMessageReceived(message))
            {
                throw new Exception("Message processing failed");
            }
            channel.BasicAck(ea.DeliveryTag, false);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            onError(e);
            channel.BasicNack(ea.DeliveryTag, false, true);
        }
    };
    channel.BasicConsume(queueName, false, consumer);
}
```

Which runs fine in my dev environment, problem is when I spin some instances of this bad boy on a Docker machine they seem to be dying after ~30 minutes, no error no nothing, execution continues but no messages are received and they disappear from rabbitMQ consumers' array.

What am I missing?

Comment: As an additional side-ish comment, I would suggest considering wrapping your `Encoding.GetString` in a try-catch, even if you only log before re-throwing (if you want the reader to die on invalid input.) Otherwise I'm not sure what the app/handler will do on a failure.

Answer (score 0):

Consumer should be changed to

```
var consumer = new AsyncEventingBasicConsumer(channel);
```

and factory should have parameter

```
factory.DispatchConsumersAsync = true;
```